# (Blazor ) Child Component not rendering

Tags: render, blazor, syncfusion

i created a Dialog component using Syncfusion and im trying to call it from a parent component but its not rendering.

This is my Parent component and here im using @ref in my child component (ModalAcceptCancel) so when i click on the delete button (in my grid) im able to call a method named OpenDialog to render or show my modal.

```
@using App.Dtos
@using App.Data
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

//This is my child component
<ModalAcceptCancel @ref="Modal"/>
//
<SfGrid @ref="SfGridProfesores" DataSource="@DsProfesores" AllowPaging="true">
    <GridColumns>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(ProfesorDto.Id) HeaderText="Identificador" TextAlign="TextAlign.Right" Width="120">
        </GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(ProfesorDto.Nombres) HeaderText="Nombre" Width="200"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn Field=@nameof(ProfesorDto.CorreoElectronico) HeaderText="Correo Electrónico" Width="150"></GridColumn>
        <GridColumn HeaderText="Acciones" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="120">
            <Template>
                @{
                    var profesor = (context as ProfesorDto);             
                    <SfButton @onclick="@(() => NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Profesor/"+profesor.Id))" CssClass="e-info">Editar</SfButton>
                    <SfButton CssClass="e-danger" @onclick="(() => DeleteProfesor(profesor.Id))">Borrar</SfButton>                                  
                }
            </Template>
        </GridColumn>
    </GridColumns>
</SfGrid>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public IReadOnlyList<ProfesorDto> DsProfesores { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public IProfesorService ProfesorService { get; set; }

    SfGrid<ProfesorDto> SfGridProfesores;

    ModalAcceptCancel Modal; 

    //Here i try to open my Modal (ChildComponent)
    private void DeleteProfesor(int id)
    {
        Modal.OpenDialog();
        //ProfesorService.BorraProfesor(id);
       // SfGridProfesores.Refresh();
    }
}
```

This is the code from my child component. My Syncfusion dialog visibility is binded to the "Is Visible property", when OpenDialog methos is called the property changes to true and it should show my modal.

```
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Popups
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons


<SfDialog Width="500px" ShowCloseIcon="true" CloseOnEscape="true" @bind-Visible="@IsVisible">
    <DialogTemplates>
        <Header> Atención </Header>
        <Content> ¿Estás seguro que deseas eliminar este elemento? </Content>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <SfButton CssClass="e-primary e-flat" @onclick="@CloseDialog">
                Aceptar
            </SfButton>
            <SfButton CssClass="e-flat" @onclick="@CloseDialog">
                Cancelar
            </SfButton>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </DialogTemplates>
</SfDialog>

@code {
    private bool IsVisible { get; set; } = false;

    public void OpenDialog()
    {
        this.IsVisible = true;
    }

    public void CloseDialog()
    {
        this.IsVisible = false;
    }
}
```

¿What im doing wrong?
¿Is there a better practice for doing this?

Im really new to developing. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that is supposed to call the modal, right ?

```
 @onclick="(() => BorrarProfesor(profesor.Id))"
```

You need this code:

```
@onclick="(() => DeleteProfesor(profesor.Id))"
```

which calls the DeleteProfesor method, passing it the professir id, from which the `Modal.OpenDialog();` is excuted...

Define as the DeleteProfesor as follows:

```
//Here i try to open my Modal (ChildComponent)
    private async void DeleteProfesor(int id)
    {
        Modal.OpenDialog();
        //ProfesorService.BorraProfesor(id);
       // SfGridProfesores.Refresh();
    }
```

I hope that helps! If you get stuck, let me know

Comment: It didn't work :(. I tried using the dialog from syncfusion from an individual page and it works fine. 

I also tried to initiliaze my IsVisible propety to True and see if the modal shows from the get go and it does. 

I dont know if im missing something or if it is an error from syncfusion because the dialog documentation has some problems.

Comment: Thank you! I changed it the code but the problem still persists :(

When i debug it the Modal.OpenDialog() executes cleanly, but for some reason doesnt show the syncfusion Dialog. But when i initiliaze my IsVisible propety to True and see if the modal shows from the get go it does. Maybe is a problem from syncfusion?

Comment: I've updated my answer once again to show you how to define DeleteProfesor. Try it and report me if it works.

Comment: No, it's not a problem from syncfusion. I think it is because you use void instead of async void. In any case, if this doesn't work, place StateHasChanged(); in the next line after Modal.OpenDialog();

Answer (score 1):

Greetings from Syncfusion support,

We have validated your reported query and shared code blocks. The **IsVisible** property is called from another razor page, hence the property changes are not affected with the SfDialog so it is not shown. We suggest you to call the **StateHasChanged()** next to the property update, to resolve the reported issue. We have also prepared a sample that tries to meet your requirements.

Sample: [https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SFDIAL~22087980339](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SFDIAL%7E22087980339)

Please let us know if the solution helps,

Regards,

Indrajith

Comment: I'm sorry but your explanation is completely wrong. The SfDialog's Visible property is bound to the parent's IsVisible property, and it should work. The issue is that he uses async void instead of async Task, and thus the runtime cannot know when the action has completed (No Task object to indicate that the action has completed), and thus, the StateHasChanged method that should be called automatically (UI click event, right ?) is skipped, and consequently no re-rendering occurs.

Comment: yes, it seems to be the exact cause. Thanks for the clarifications..!